# POWERSHELL: piping exe file output in to variable

Tags: powershell, write-host

I am trying to execute a sript to run exe file, get the output, search through the output and then if its true do soemthing:

```
$output = cmd /c file.exe additionalvariables --batch | 
    write-host | 
    where-object($_ -eq "Finished  with Success") #finished with success does not work

if ( -eq "Finished  with Success") # I need to perform a check
{
    "Command executed"
    $tcp.Dispose()
    Exit 0
}
else
{
    "There is an issue with file.exe additionalvariables command"
    EXIT 1
    $tcp.Dispose()
}
```

So the finished with success does not work in line 1, do you know how to check if statement? `if ( -eq "Finished  with Success")`.

Comment: What is the value of $LASTEXITCODE after the .exe completes?

Comment: Whats the output look like? Give an example

Comment: `where-object($_ -eq "Finished  with Success")` should be `where-object{$_ -eq "Finished  with Success"}` and `write-host` should not be used as you are sending data to another stream. Just remove that part of the pipe and try again.

Comment: This the output: `Batch interface for EXE component v.4.01.47
Copyright 2015

EXE Execution = 1 Mode = parameter Finished  with Success 
Executing StoredProcedure SP 1
Executing StoredProcedure SP 2`

Comment: why won't you do something like: start-process cmd -ArgumentList '/c file.exe additionalvariables --batch' -RedirectStandardOutput c:\1.txt

Comment: In general, the .exe should return zero (0) if it is successful and something other than zero (0) if there is an error. String matching should not be required.

Comment: yeah, I didnt write this exe, I am just trying to pipe the output then check if it was successful or not. I have also tried without 'write-host |' it seems it is working but now I cannot see any output from the file. It would be very useful to see it as it does operation on the database.

Comment: did you try to redirectoutput like i proposed?

Comment: thanks, I was able to solve my problem by piping it out to file then parsing the file. Its not ideal scenario as I wanted to avoid creating new files but its the simplest. thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you would expect the .exe to return zero (0) for success and anything other than zero (0) for failure. Parsing the text output is not generally required. Below is some code that might get you started on something.

```
$output = cmd /c returnit.bat 0
$LASTEXITCODE
Write-Verbose "===$output==="

$output.gettype()

if ($output -match '.*Finished with Success.*') {
    "Command executed"
    $tcp.Dispose()
    Exit 0
}
else
{
    "There is an issue with file.exe additionalvariables command"
    EXIT 1
    $tcp.Dispose()
}
```

=== returnit.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /A "IT=0"
IF "%1" NEQ "" (SET /A "IT=%1")
IF %IT% EQU 0 (
    ECHO a line
    ECHO Finished with Success
    ECHO another line
)
EXIT /B %IT%
```